# I need to make sure my town's population won't decrement less than 0, But I am having trouble writing this code with out Bugs

Tags: xcode, swift, macos

```
class Zombie: Monster {
    var walksWithLimp = true

    final override func terrorizeTown() {
        var message : String
        town?.changePopulation(-10)
        super.terrorizeTown()

        if changePopulation = 0 {
            message  = "Cannot Decrement"
        }

        print(messsage) 
    }

    func changeName(name: String, walksWithLimp: Bool) {
        self.name = name
        self.walksWithLimp = walksWithLimp
    }
}
```

My errors are on the if statement and the message.

Comment: Please share your error message.

Comment: The compiler error `use of '=' in a boolean context, did you mean '=='?` should be very clear.

Answer (score 2):

You are using using the '=' operator instead of the '=='.
Best if you use '<=' 0 to cover negative values.

```
if changePopulation <= 0 
{
  message  = "Cannot Decrement"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change this:

```
if changePopulation = 0
```

To this:

```
if changePopulation == 0
```

The first expression sets `changePopulation` to 0. The second evaluates as a boolean 0 or 1 depending on whether or not `changePopulation` is equal to 0. This is a common mistake; always be careful with those equal signs in languages like this.

Answer (score 0):

Since you asked to ensure that the population doesn't drop below zero, then Town.changePopulation(i:Int) must not do this check. This can't be done unless you have a way to query the town's population. Let's assume Town has a property called population. if so: This will work

```
class Zombie: Monster {

    var walksWithLimp = true

    final override func terrorizeTown() {

        var message : String

        if let town = town { // Ensure town exists
            var populationChange = 10

            if town.population < populationChange {
                populationChange = town.population
            }

            town.changePopulation(-populationChange)
            super.terrorizeTown()

            if populationChange == 0 {
                message  = "Cannot Decrement"
                print(messsage)
            }
        } else {
            message = "No Town Available"
            print(messsage)
        }
    }

    func changeName(name: String, walksWithLimp: Bool) {
        self.name = name
        self.walksWithLimp = walksWithLimp
    }
}
```

Comment: My submission assumes that you do not have access to the source code of Town and Monster. If you do, this is not proper OO. Town's changePopulation(i) should protect Towns from negative population. (Classes should protect themselves from corruption not depend on clients.) Also, unless Zombies are the only Monster that reduces population, Monster should be dealing with uninhabited towns, not Zombie.